# IndexError when trying to perform ffill() on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone explain what this error means? I have a large dataframe with lots of NaN values. I am simply trying to fill in certain columns with the previous value. Here is the code:

```
import tables as tb
import pandas as pd
```

Here I open up some pytables and import the table into dataframes

```
FGBL = tb.open_file("C:\\Users\\SUPER\\Documents\\NewQSPythonSamples\\FGBL.h5")

FGBM = tb.open_file("C:\\Users\\SUPER\\Documents\\NewQSPythonSamples\\FGBM.h5")

FGBS = tb.open_file("C:\\Users\\SUPER\\Documents\\NewQSPythonSamples\\FGBS.h5")

FGBLtable = FGBL.root.trade.Z4
FGBMtable = FGBM.root.trade.Z4
FGBStable = FGBS.root.trade.Z4

FGBStableq = FGBS.root.quote.Z4
FGBMtableq = FGBM.root.quote.Z4
FGBLtableq = FGBL.root.quote.Z4

fgbltrade = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBLtable.read())
fgbmtrade = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBMtable.read())
fgbstrade = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBLtable.read())

fgblquote = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBLtableq.read())
fgbmquote = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBMtableq.read())
fgbsquote = pd.DataFrame.from_records(FGBStableq.read())
```

then i convert the datetime from timestamp to datetime format

```
fgbltrade["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgbltrade.dateTime, unit="s")
fgbmtrade["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgbmtrade.dateTime, unit="s")
fgbstrade["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgbstrade.dateTime, unit="s")

fgblquote["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgblquote.dateTime, unit="s")
fgbmquote["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgbmquote.dateTime, unit="s")
fgbsquote["DateTimes"] = pd.to_datetime(fgbsquote.dateTime, unit="s")
```

perform some simple maths on the frames then drop NaN and unneeded columns

```
fgblquote["VWPfgbl"] = (fgblquote.askPrc*fgblquote.bidSize + fgblquote.bidPrc*fgblquote.askSize)/(fgblquote.askSize + fgblquote.bidSize)
fgbmquote["VWPfgbm"] = (fgbmquote.askPrc*fgbmquote.bidSize + fgbmquote.bidPrc*fgbmquote.askSize)/(fgbmquote.askSize + fgbmquote.bidSize)
fgbsquote["VWPfgbs"] = (fgbsquote.askPrc*fgbsquote.bidSize + fgbsquote.bidPrc*fgbsquote.askSize)/(fgbsquote.askSize + fgbsquote.bidSize)

fgblquote = fgblquote.dropna()
fgbmquote = fgbmquote.dropna()
fgbsquote = fgbsquote.dropna()

fgblquote = fgblquote.drop(["askPrc", "askSize", "bidPrc", "bidSize", "dateTime"], axis=1)
fgbmquote = fgbmquote.drop(["askPrc", "askSize", "bidPrc", "bidSize", "dateTime"], axis=1)
fgbsquote = fgbsquote.drop(["askPrc", "askSize", "bidPrc", "bidSize", "dateTime"], axis=1)
```

then I merge the frames together

```
df = pd.merge(fgbltrade, fgbmtrade, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
df = pd.merge(df, fgbstrade, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
df = pd.merge(df, fgblquote, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
df = pd.merge(df, fgbmquote, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
df = pd.merge(df, fgbsquote, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
```

and try to fill forwards

```
df = df["VWPfgbl"].ffill()
df = df["VWPfgbm"].ffill()
df = df["VWPfgbs"].ffill()
```

and the error:

```
In [3]: df = df["VWPfgbl"].ffill()
   ...: df = df["VWPfgbm"].ffill()
   ...: df = df["VWPfgbs"].ffill()
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-20f62c2a5da9> in <module>()
      1 df = df["VWPfgbl"].ffill()
----> 2 df = df["VWPfgbm"].ffill()
      3 df = df["VWPfgbs"].ffill()
      4 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    482     def __getitem__(self, key):
    483         try:
--> 484             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    485 
    486             if not np.isscalar(result):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1214             # python 3
   1215             if np.isscalar(key):  # pragma: no cover
-> 1216                 raise IndexError(key)
   1217             raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   1218  

IndexError: VWPfgbm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you're overwriting your `df` variable with a single column from a previous value.

```
df = df["VWPfgbl"].ffill()
df = df["VWPfgbm"].ffill()
df = df["VWPfgbs"].ffill()
```

The first line there will assign the `df` variable such that it is a single (ffilled) column of your original dataframe. That's why it fails on the second line, because `df` now doesn't have any other columns, and so you get an `IndexError`.

You should re-write the code to something like

```
df["VWPfgbl"] = df["VWPfgbl"].ffill()
df["VWPfgbm"] = df["VWPfgbm"].ffill()
df["VWPfgbs"] = df["VWPfgbs"].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error,

```
IndexError: VWPfgbm
```

is saying that `df` has no column named `'VWPfgbm'`.
You can check that fact by inspecting `df.columns`.

You might be wondering, if `fgbmquote["VWPfgbm"]`, and

```
df = pd.merge(df, fgblquote, on='DateTimes', how = "outer")
```

how can in be that `df` does not contain a column, `"VWPfgbm"`?

One reason why this might happen is if both `df` and `fgblquote` have `"VWPfgbm"` columns. Then `pd.merge` *disambiguates* them by naming the columns `"VWPfgbm_x"` and `"VWPfgbm_y"` in the merged DataFrame. See the [`suffixes` parameter of the `pd.merge` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'VWPfgbm':range(3), 'baz':list('ABC')})
bar = pd.DataFrame({'VWPfgbm':range(3,6), 'baz':list('CAB')})
pd.merge(foo, bar, on='baz', how='outer')
```

yields

```
   VWPfgbm_x baz  VWPfgbm_y
0          0   A          4
1          1   B          5
2          2   C          3
```

Comment: I didn't spot that there was an error with merging. Thanks for pointing it out. I knew what my resulting frame did not make sense!